# How to write Firebase's instance in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class HiltModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAuthentication(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
}
```

Now I'm learning Kotlin. I think if I want to use an instance, I should do it below:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class HiltModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAuthentication(){
       FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth()
    }
}
```

But this is not right. why not use Firebase.auth(), using Firebase.auth issue it's instance?

And I have another question.
why not using "{}" in fun provideAuthentication(),using only ":" gets property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way in which you can do that in Kotlin would be:

```
@Provides
fun provideFirebaseAuth() = Firebase.auth
```

So the object that will be injected would be of type [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth).

Please note that `auth` is **not** a function so it can be called using `()` (parentheses). It's a property of type FirebaseAuth. To be more precise it's an [extension property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/ktx/package-summary#auth_1).

Comment: Thank you,Alex. Why we don't need to use "()" to issue instance? is that the singleton property?

Comment: This is because `auth` is not a function so it can be called using `()`. It's a property of type FirebaseAuth. To be more precise it's an [extension property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/ktx/package-summary#auth_1), right?

Comment: Hi, Alex. Thank you for supporting me. Make sense!! I have another question. Calling this function "fun provideAuthentication()" return the property,right?

Comment: So   
`fun provideAuthentication(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth` 
equals 
`fun provideAuthentication(){ 
return FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
}`.
Is this right?

Comment: No. `fun provideAuthentication(): FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth` is equal to `fun provideAuthentication(){  return Firebase.auth }` or even simpler, `fun provideFirebaseAuth() = Firebase.auth` without the return type. Kotlin already knows the type of the object.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you, Alex.
I have another question. [How to write sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250179/how-to-write-sealed-class-in-kotlin)
If you support me, I will be so helped.
Please! Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear that is clear now.  Regarding the other question, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: Hey, Shun. So can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi, Alex. Thank you for caring me. So far that's OK. When I have any question, plz answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Alex. I have one question about this topic. You told me  I can write here `fun provideAuthentication(){  return Firebase.auth }`. So can I write `fun provideAuthentication():FirebaseAuth {  return Firebase.auth }` I think `FirebaseAuth` is protocol for the class. Please teach me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Is `FirebaseAuth` the function return's type, it? Now I am writing codes. I got it. Thank you.

Comment: If you use `fun provideAuthentication():FirebaseAuth {  return Firebase.auth }` it means that you explicitly set the return type of the method, which is fine.