# How to write sealed class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
sealed class DestinationScreen(val route:String){
    object Signup: DestinationScreen(route = "signup")
}
```

Now I am developing navigation screen above.
I don't understand this statement.

`object Signup: DestinationScreen(route = "signup")`

I think Signup is property. So to set it, should we write this below?

`object Signup = DestinationScreen(route = "signup")`

Why does not using `=` issue the instance and set the Signup property?

Please teach me. Thank you.

Comment: You can write subclasses outside the sealed class. Maybe then you'll understand better what's going on. See the basic example in the official Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. `Signup` is not a property. It's basically a class which extends `DestinationScreen` except it's a special class `object` which acts as a singleton and is initiated at the same point it's described. That's why you write it like that.

Why it looks like a property to you is you happen to declare it in another class (which makes it an inner class). But you can declare it outside of the class too.

More about Kotlin objects https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html

Answer (score 1):

[Sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) represent a class with a fixed number of subclasses. At first, you declare the parent class, for example, a class that describes `Screen` of your app. Then, you declare all children of this class. For example, `HomeScreen` and `LoginScreen`:

```
sealed class Screen

class HomeScreen : Screen()
class LoginScreen : Screen()
```

All subclasses can be written outside of the parent class (but must be located in the same file due to compiler limitations).

You can use the [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview) keyword instead of `class` modifier in case of a class has no properties. It means that the object keyword declares a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using inheritance, not an assigment.

A sealed class is a class which subtypes are known by the compiler so it allows you to create flow controls by type:

```
sealed class Result {
     data class Success(val data...): Result()
     data class Error(val exception...): Result()
}
```

So you can do:

```
when(val result = ...) {
    is Success -> result.data
    is Error -> result.error
}
```

Whith normal inheritance like on interfaces, open classes or abstract classes you dont know the typed thar inherit from the super type.

Comment: You forget to add inheritance in your example like this: `class Success(val data): Result`