# Firebase.auth is a unresolved reference. How can I fix it?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'll try to follow the Firebase Login tutorial, but these lines break my code because `auth` is an unresolved reference. How can I fix it?

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           auth = Firebase.auth
    }
}
```

Comment: when you follow the firebase docs make sure to follow either java or kotlin because you cant add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'` and your project in kotlin (for example) as the answers said below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the following behavior:

> Firebase.auth is a unresolved reference

Most likely because of two main reasons. The first one would be because you didn't add the [proper dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). By the time I'm answering this question, you should use:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.5.0")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
//
```

Since you're using Kotlin, always be sure to add the dependency that ends with `ktx`. Once you add that, there is an **import** that should be added inside the activity/fragment where you need to use an instance of `FirebaseAuth`:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
```

Right after that, you can either use:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

Or:

```
auth = Firebase.auth
```

Both return the same instance. The latter one is an [extension property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/ktx/package-summary#auth_1), which is the preferred type of instantiation in Kotlin. I have recently answered a similar question regarding this topic:

- [How to write Firebase's instance in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222317/how-to-write-firebases-instance-in-kotlin)

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried and It works.